# How to group by the amount of values in an array in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, grouping, go-gorm

I have a posts table with few columns including a liked_by column which's type is an int array.
As I can't post the table here I'll post a single post's JSON structure which comes as below

```
 "post": {
    "ID": 1,
    "CreatedAt": "2022-08-15T11:06:44.386954+05:30",
    "UpdatedAt": "2022-08-15T11:06:44.386954+05:30",
    "DeletedAt": null,
    "title": "Pofst1131",
    "postText": "yyhfgwegfewgewwegwegwegweg",
    "img": "fegjegwegwg.com",
    "userName": "AthfanFasee",
    "likedBy": [
        3,
        1,
        4
    ],
    "createdBy": 1,
}
```

I'm trying to send posts in the order they are liked (Most Liked Posts). Which should order the posts according to the number of values inside the liked_by array. How can I achieve this in Postgres?

For a side note, I'm using Go lang with GORM ORM but I'm using raw SQL builder instead of ORM tools. I'll be fine with solving this problem using go lang as well. The way I achieved this in MongoDB and NodeJS is to group by the size of liked by array and add a total like count field and sort using that field as below

```
if(sort === 'likesCount') {
    data = Post.aggregate([         
        {
          $addFields: {
            totalLikesCount: { $size: "$likedBy" } 
          }
        }    
     ])
     data = data.sort('-totalLikesCount');

} else {
    data = data.sort('-createdAt') ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a native query.
Provided that the table column that contains the sample data is called `post`, then

```sql
select <list of expressions> from the_table 
 order by json_array_length(post->'likedBy') desc;
```

Unrelated but why don't you try a normalized data design?

**Edit**

Now that I know your table structure here is the updated query. Use [array_length](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

```sql
select <list of expressions> from public.posts
 order by array_length(liked_by, 1) desc nulls last;
```

You may also wish to add a `where` clause too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. This is giving me the following error "ERROR: operator does not exist: posts -> unknown (SQLSTATE 42883)" and here's the query I tried "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(posts->'liked_by') DESC". I also tried to use JSONB instead of JSON. My array in db looks like this "{1,2,3}".  If I try this "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(posts->liked_by) DESC", It's giving me this error "ERROR: operator does not exist: posts -> integer[] (SQLSTATE 42883)"

Comment: Plus. post your table structure

Comment: `type Post struct {
 gorm.Model
 Title string `gorm:"not null" json:"title"`
 PostText string `gorm:"not null" json:"postText"`
 Img string `gorm:"not null" json:"img"`
 UserName string `gorm:"not null" json:"userName"`
 LikedBy pq.Int64Array `gorm:"type:integer[];uniqueIndex" json:"likedBy"`
 CreatedBy uint `gorm:"index:idx_createdBy;not null" json:"createdBy"`
 User User `gorm:"foreignKey:CreatedBy"`
}` This is the post model. I migrated db using this

Comment: This is not a table structure really.

Comment: You mean my structure is wrong or I'm posting the wrong thing? I'm new to sql, Sorry for the inconvenience. I have studied it well but idk what am I doing wrong

Comment: Your structure is what you need it to be. This is a GORM model definition which translates into a database table and not the structure (i.e. DDL) of the table itself.  If  you  find it in your database then I will be able to help with native SQL.

Comment: https://imgur.com/GQG3xr4 I Hope this is what you are asking for. Also here's the SQL code I found inside table plus ` CREATE TABLE "public"."posts" ("id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass), "created_at" timestamptz, "updated_at" timestamptz, "deleted_at" timestamptz, "title" text NOT NULL, "post_text" text NOT NULL, "img" text NOT NULL, "user_name" text NOT NULL, "liked_by" _int4, "created_by" int8 NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_posts_user" FOREIGN KEY ("created_by") REFERENCES "public"."users"("id"), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));`

Comment: This is working except if a post got no likes at all (null value) it's getting it first instead of the most liked post

Comment: Add `nulls last`. I have updated my answer again.

Comment: Working!! Thanks Champ ^^ If you have any spare time, pls let me know what you meant by a normalized data design.

Comment: Just google "normalized data design". A lot of good info out there.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I wanted to ask one more thing. How did you solve my problem tho? Is it your experience with PostgreSQL all the way or Did you go through docs quickly? If you did go through docs what was your thinking process or your steps? I'm just trying to learn from you

Comment: These are long long years, Athfan.

Comment: Hoping to become someone like you (both in knowledge and helping others) one day.  Have an amazing one :)